# How to use AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED in Scrapy?

Tags: ajax, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I read [this](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html) from documentation

how it works the  AJAXCRAWL in Scrapy and what happens when it's True?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config you are referring to seems to be mentioned in [midleware source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/ajaxcrawl.py):

```
class AjaxCrawlMiddleware(object):
    """
    Handle 'AJAX crawlable' pages marked as crawlable via meta tag.
    For more info see https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started.
    """

    def __init__(self, settings):
        if not settings.getbool('AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED'):
            raise NotConfigured
```

So to answer your question, what it does is that it enables crawling support for websites that use AJAX and implement [the google specs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started). You will also probably need to enable the [downloader middleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html)